# How to modify a class when a specific class exists on the same element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have my (simplified here) bootstrap navbar here.

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
  height: 100px;
}
.navbar-nav >li >a {
  line-height: 100px
}
```

I just want to shrink the `navbar` when I add the class `.shrink` to `nav`. Pretty easy, just adding the following to my css:

```js
.shrink {
    height: 80px;
}
```

The problem is: the `line-height` of `.navbar >li >a` stays `100px` - is there a way I can affect this with css only?

Comment: `.navbar.shrink > li > a { line-height: 80px; }` ?!

Comment: @deceze li isn't a child descendent of .navbar, it's a child of .navbar-nav

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode Ah, true, I was merely mimicking the original CSS without looking too closely. Well, it should get the point across anyway I'd hope.

Comment: @deceze: Dontfeedthecode is obviously right, sorry. I've tried to keep my example simple - but unfortunately I've kept a bit to simple. fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
.navbar {
  height: 100px;
}

.navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px
}

.navbar > .navbar-nav > li > a {
  line-height: 100px
}

.navbar.shrink > .navbar-nav > li > a {
  line-height: 80px
}
```

Comment: @Brettetete that's not very helpful, based on the information you provided there's no reason for it not to work - you're going to have to do a jsfiddle or share a link to the issue if there are other things going on.

Comment: Got it working by removing the child selector. `.navbar.shrink .navbar-nav > li >`

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
.shrink a {
    line-height: <whatever>;
}
```

That will apply the styles you want to an a element contained in an element with the shrink class.